# Problem with Stack traces in android market

Tags: android, google-play

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.falling.inairproandmark/com.falling.inairproandmark.Q9Popup}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:876)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:634)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:219)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
at com.falling.inairproandmark.Q9Popup.onCreate(Q9Popup.java:36)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:65)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:352)
at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:69)
... 26 more
```

==

here's my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



    <Button android:background="@drawable/q9popup" android:id="@+id/qnine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </Button>


    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adUnitId="**********"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER"
                           ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>                               
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I don't understand why I keep getting this error :S

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: What version of the AdMob SDK are you using? 4.1.1? Do you call AdView.destroy() from your Activity's onDestroy()?

Comment: What line in your XML file is #9?

Comment: 1) AbsoluteLayout is deprecated

Comment: Line #9 in xml is<Button android:background="@drawable/q9popup" android:id="@+id/qnine"

Answer (score 0):

Android cannot allocate the memory for the Button. Pre-Honeycomb allocates the memory for a bitmap natively, outside the Dalvik VM, using malloc and has to rely on Java finalizers to free that memory again. Unless you call Bitmap.recycle that is.

See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk&feature=player_detailpage#t=650s for some info on allocation of Bitmaps.

So you have to figure out why external allocation is so high in your app. Maybe AdMob is the cause. Make sure to invoke AdView.destroy in your activity's onDestroy.

Comment: thanks i have added this code in every button of my activities onPause();
     onStop();
     onDestroy(); . i hope this works out. also the AdView.destroy isnt working it says destroy isnt recognised. i have the latest admob 4.1.1